# CLLocation distanceFromLocation (in Swift?)

Tags: swift, cllocation, cllocationdistance

Can somebody please help me convert the following Objective-C statement to Swift?

```
CLLocationDistance distance = [fromLocation distanceFromLocation:toLocation];
```

I know that it must be simple to do that. I am brand new to iOS programming and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you! :-)

Comment: Use Playground to figure it out. The documentation shows you exactly what this call should look like.

Comment: Use the documentation: `func distanceFromLocation(location: CLLocation!) -> CLLocationDistance`. In Xcode Command click on `CLLocationDistance` to get to the documentation and then search for `distanceFromLocation`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
let distance = fromLocation.distanceFromLocation(toLocation)
```

New syntax:

```
let distance = aLocation.distance(from: anotherLocation)
```

Comment: now deprecated so use: `let distance = location1.distance(from: location2)`

Answer (score 4):

```
func distanceFromLocation(_ location: CLLocation!) -> CLLocationDistance
```

Returns the distance (in meters) from the receiver’s location to the specified location.

Read more here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation: