# get direction and route with MKMapView

Tags: swift, mapkit

I have been trying to get directions and routes with MKMapView without using Maps or google maps app.
I want to use it in my app with opening up other apps.
Can someone help?

Here is what I have but I want to change it so I can get the direction and routing on my app. I have Swift 4 and Xcode 9!

```
//Getting direction of location
    @objc func getDirections(){
        if let selectedPin = selectedPin {
            let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPin)
            let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
            mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
        }
    }


extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
            return nil
        }
        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.red
        pinView?.canShowCallout = true
        let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: smallSquare))
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Car"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getDirections), for: .touchUpInside)

        pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
        return pinView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have been trying to get directions and routes with MKMapView without using Maps or google maps app.
>   I want to use it in my app with opening up other apps. Can someone help?

You can't start a navigation inside your apps. What you can do is drawing a path between two points and get information like the distance or expected driving/walking time.

Search for `Distance between two points MapKit`and you will find a bunch of results. For example have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993625/how-can-i-calculate-the-distance-between-two-points-in-mkmapview), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44139786/calculate-distance-between-my-location-and-a-mapkit-pin-on-swift) or [this swift 4 soultion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304340/how-to-find-out-distance-between-coordinates)